# Почему всегда выбирается только самый первый элемент? JS

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Есть код:

```js
let balance = 0;
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_add")).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""),)
    balance = balance + sum
    alert("balance = " + balance)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<h4><a id="1" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span></h4>
<h4><a id="2" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">20</span></h4>
<h4><a id="3" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">30</span></h4>
<h4><a id="4" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">40</span></h4>
<h4><a id="5" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">50</span></h4>
<h4><a id="6" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">60</span></h4>
```

В моей голове он должен брать значение `item_price`, прибавлять его к `balance` и потом идет `alert` переменной `balance`.

Но почему-то он берет значение `item_price` только под `id 1` и записывает в `balance` только его, вне зависимости от того на какой `id` я нажал.

Можете помочь пофиксить код?

Буду благодарен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) выбирает первый элемент, который отвечает условиям селектора, в данном случае он выбирал самый верхний `item_price`, поэтому Вы и получали такой результат.

Что бы решить эту проблему можно "оттолкнуться" от элемента на который пришелся клик, "подняться" наверх до его родителя и заново выполнить поиск вниз до нужного элемента с текстом:

```
// т.е заменить
document.querySelector

// на
event.target.closest("h4").querySelector
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
let balance = 0
const handleClick = event => {
  let sum = event.target.closest("h4").querySelector(".item_price").textContent
  sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""))
  balance = balance + sum
  alert("balance = " + balance)
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_add")).forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```html
<h4><a id="1" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span></h4>
<h4><a id="2" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">20</span></h4>
<h4><a id="3" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">30</span></h4>
<h4><a id="4" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">40</span></h4>
<h4><a id="5" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">50</span></h4>
<h4><a id="6" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">60</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

Моё решение не столь универсальное. Я просто "поднялся" к родительскому елементу и взял следующего соседа.

```js
let balance = 0;
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_add")).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent;
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
    balance += sum;
    alert("balance = " + balance)
  })
})
```

```html
<h4><a id="1" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span></h4>
<h4><a id="2" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">20</span></h4>
<h4><a id="3" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">30</span></h4>
<h4><a id="4" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">40</span></h4>
<h4><a id="5" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">50</span></h4>
<h4><a id="6" class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">60</span></h4>
```

Comment: @Vasily, ну я пока писал код Ваш ответ не видел. И к слову, может кто ответит насчет производительности, может какую-то деталь укажет. Ничего плохого в этом нету, тем более, что используются разные методы и свойства. Цель моих ответов - получить опыт, а не репутацию.

Comment: @Vasily, и что значит "копирую". Пока нигде идентичного не вижу :)